# Conversion from polar to rectangular, loss of solution

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

I want to convert $r=3\tan(\theta)$ to rectangular coordinates.
According to [this site](https://www.emathhelp.net/en/calculators/calculus-2/polar-rectangular-equation-calculator/?type=r&f=r%3Dtan%283theta%29) the answer is $x^3(x(x^2 - 3y^2)\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} - y(3x^2 - y^2)) = 0$

However, when I draw implicit graph [here](https://www.emathhelp.net/en/calculators/calculus-1/online-graphing-calculator/?x%5E3*(x*(x%5E2%20-%203*y%5E2)*sqrt(x%5E2+%2By%5E2)%20-%20y*(3*x%5E2%20-%20y%5E2))%20=%200), it misses the part of the graph, drawn in [polar coordinates](https://www.emathhelp.net/en/calculators/calculus-1/online-graphing-calculator/?r=tan(3t)).

Where am I wrong?

Comment: In your question must be $r=\tan 3\theta$. The difference is due to taking $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ in equation, so $r$ must be non-negative. But when you make polar plot you can plot with negative $r$ using origin symmetrt. If you make polar plot $r=\frac{\tan 3\theta +|\tan 3\theta|}{2}$ (this excludes case $r<0$), you'll get the same result.

Comment: What you wrote in your question and what you input in that site are two different things. Look closely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be precise with your definition of a polar plot.

When you write $r = \tan 3\theta$, you implicitly allow $r$ to be negative. Thus, the point $(r,\theta)$ may appear as $(-r,\theta+\pi)$.

When you convert to Cartesian coordinates, you take $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, thus prohibiting $r$ to become negative. No wonder, you lose some branches.

If the polar plot is what you want, you need to write $\pm\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ or effectively get rid of $\pm$ sign by squaring [again](https://www.emathhelp.net/en/calculators/calculus-1/online-graphing-calculator/?x%5E3*(x*(x%5E2%20-%203*y%5E2)*sqrt(x%5E2+%2By%5E2)%20-%20y*(3*x%5E2%20-%20y%5E2))%20=%200):
$$
x^2(x^2 - 3y^2)^2(x^2 + y^2) = y^2(3x^2 - y^2)^2
$$